# JavaScript - Copy item reference of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The answer might be obvious  but I didn't find out. I have this code :

```js
const arr = ["Hello"];
let currentStr = arr[0];
currentStr += " world";
console.log(currentStr); // prints "Hello world"
console.log(arr); // prints ["Hello"]
```

I just want to copy the string reference so when I change the `currentStr` value, it also change its reference in the array (here the first item of the `arr` array).

```js
const arr = ["Hello"];
let currentStr = arr[0];
currentStr += " world";
console.log(currentStr); // prints "Hello world"
console.log(arr); // expect print ["Hello world"]
```

Comment: you are not pushing into the array - you are just joint two `strings` together - hence why the print `[Hello]` from the original `arr`

Comment: `arr[0] += " world"` did you try like this or you want entirely different things,?

Comment: @Always No I just want to concat the first item, not pushing into the array

Comment: @MuratÇimen No I just want to concat to the reference

Comment: string is immutable. When you change it, its reference changes.

Comment: @MustafaArslan So why it doesn't change the first item of the array ?

Comment: @Esporia Because it has old reference. Reference of currentStr changes. `currentStr += " world"` returns new string.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript strings are immutable. I.e. when you make a change to a string behind the scenes Javascript is making a new copy of that string. Arrays are slightly different. You can mutate arrays. I.e. change what they are storing.

To achieve what you want you can use the splice method on the array to replace the 'Hello' string with a new string called 'Hello' + ' World'. Here is the code for it.

```
const arr = ['Hello']
arr.splice(0,1, arr[0] + ' World') 
console.log(arr) // ['Hello World']
```

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on Arrays, and the splice method.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ["Hello"];
var currentStr=[];
let newStr= arr[0]+" World"; 
currentStr.push(newStr)
console.log(currentStr); //
console.log(arr); //
```

Comment: Leaving it open but please add an explanatory line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by re-assigning *currentStr* to *arr[0]*.

```
const arr = ["Hello"];
let currentStr = arr[0];
currentStr += " world";
console.log(currentStr); // prints "Hello world"
arr[0] = currentStr;
console.log(arr); // prints ["Hello world"]
```